# ASP NET CORE 2.1 IIS LOCALHOST CONNECTION REFUSED

Tags: iis, asp.net-core, connection, runtime-error

I can run my application on Visual Studio 2017 but when I load it on to IIS I get localhost connection refused error. It is an app with login page and I created this with identity scaffold.Could you please help!!!

**IdentityHostingStartup.cs**

```
public class IdentityHostingStartup : IHostingStartup
{
    public void Configure(IWebHostBuilder builder)
    {
        builder.ConfigureServices((context, services) => {
            services.AddDbContext<StockControlContext>(options =>
                options.UseSqlServer(
                    context.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));


            services.AddDefaultIdentity<StockControlUser>()
                .AddEntityFrameworkStores<StockControlContext>().AddDefaultTokenProviders().AddDefaultUI();

            services.Configure<IdentityOptions>(options =>
            {
                // Password settings
                options.Password.RequireDigit = false;
                options.Password.RequiredLength = 0;
                options.Password.RequireNonAlphanumeric = false;
                options.Password.RequireUppercase = false;
                options.Password.RequireLowercase = false;
                options.Password.RequiredUniqueChars = 0;


            });
            services.Configure<IISOptions>(options =>
            {
                options.ForwardClientCertificate= false;

            });


        });
    }
 }
}
```

**startup.cs**

```
public class Startup
{
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {

        var environment = services.BuildServiceProvider().GetRequiredService<IHostingEnvironment>();

        services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(options =>
        {
            options.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30);
        });

        services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
        {
            // This lambda determines whether user consent for non-essential cookies is needed for a given request.

            options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => true;
            options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.None;

        });
        /*  services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
              options.UseSqlServer(
                  Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
          services.AddDefaultIdentity<IdentityUser>()
              .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();*/


        services.AddDbContext<BAR_ERPContext>(options =>
   options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
        services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1);

        services.AddMvc().AddSessionStateTempDataProvider();
        services.AddSession(options => {
            options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
        });

        services.AddBootstrapPagerGenerator(options =>
        {
            // Use default pager options.
            options.ConfigureDefault();
        });
        services.Configure<PagerOptions>(Configuration.GetSection("Pager"));
        services.Configure<IISOptions>(options =>
        {
            options.ForwardClientCertificate = false;
        });

    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {


        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            app.UseDatabaseErrorPage();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
            app.UseHsts();
        }

        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseStaticFiles();
        app.UseCookiePolicy();
        app.UseSession();
        app.UseAuthentication();

        app.UseMvc(routes =>
        {
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "default",
                template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        });
    }
}
```

**program.cs**

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        CreateWebHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
    }

    public static IWebHostBuilder CreateWebHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .UseStartup<Startup>();
```

I added below code for both startup.cs and  IdentityHostingStartup.cs

```
  services.Configure<IISOptions>(options =>
        {
            options.ForwardClientCertificate = false;
        });
```

I also tried creating new project without login page in asp.net core. It worked fine on IIS. But asp.net core project with scafolded identity anonymous login is not working on IIS, however it works fine on VS 2017.

Could you please help thx.

Comment: Show your IIS setup as well as the URL in your web browser please. The error message simply means the URL does not match the site on IIS. A tool like Jexus Manager can show you more about the bindings and the expected URLs, https://docs.jexusmanager.com/tutorials/binding-diagnostics.html

Comment: Hi I downloaded jexus and its report is - BINDING: http 127.0.0.1:999:localhost
 * The networking must be properly set up to forward requests from web browsers to 127.0.0.1:999 on this machine.
 * Web browsers should use URL http://localhost:999. Requests must have Host header of "localhost".
   Start DNS query for localhost.
   DNS Query returns 2 result(s).
    * [::1]
    * 127.0.0.1 - I think i have to change DNS settings

Comment: No matter what you plan to change next, make sure you use Jexus Manager to better understand the aftermath of that change. The more you change bindings/DNS, the more clearly you should understand the basics.

Comment: Hi, I made some code change and deploy the app with Jexus Manager and it is now working. I deployed the app from IIS Manager and Ajax did not work this time. But when I deploy it from Jexus it is working. Jexus is using command prompt for deployment and I think this solved Ajax issue and some code change solved CONN REFUSED issue. Thx.